# How to avoid duplicated values uisng rbind and data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I want to merge values in a data frame.

My toy example is this one:

```
table1 <-c()

a <- data.frame("p.value" = c(0.01, 0.05), "Pos" = c(1, 2))
b <- data.frame("p.value" = 0.005, "Pos" = 1)

table1 <- rbind(table1,data.frame(a, b))
```

This is giving me this output:

```
> table1
p.value Pos p.value.1 Pos.1
1    0.01   1     0.005     1
2    0.05   2     0.005     1
```

But my desired output is:

```
> table1
p.value Pos p.value.1 Pos.1
1    0.01   1     0.005     1
2    0.05   2      NA       NA
```

Could you please tell me how I could avoid to have the duplicated values and fill with NAs?

Comment: I can see an ugly solution which would be to fill the smaller data frame with `NA` to match the size of the other one before applying `rbind()`, but there is probably a nicer solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be to make both the dataframes of same  number of rows and then `cbind`

```
cbind(a, b[seq_len(nrow(a)), ])

#   p.value Pos p.value Pos
#1     0.01   1   0.005   1
#NA    0.05   2      NA  NA
```

Comment: I want to use this in a for loop, that's why I am selecting this answer. Other answers posted here are also correct.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't absolutely need the other `Pos` columns, you can use a `left_join` from `tidyverse`.

```
table1 <- rbind(table1, left_join(a, b, by=c("Pos"), suffix = c("", ".1")))

  p.value Pos p.value.1
1    0.01   1     0.005
2    0.05   2        NA
```

Answer (score 2):

To obtain your desired table1 without merging by `Pos`, you could merge by `rownames`:

```r
tbl_a <- a %>% mutate(names = rownames(a))
tbl_b <- b %>% mutate(names = rownames(b))

table1 <- tbl_a %>% 
  full_join(tbl_b, by = "names")
table1
```

If you want to transform back to `data.frame`, use

```
table1 %>%
  select(-names) %>%
  as.data.frame
```

which results in exactly the data frame you posted